# Getting antonyms using the R Wordnet package

Tags: r, wordnet

I'm trying to get antonyms of words using the wordnet package. This works for some words while returning an error I don't really get for others. The function is basically just the usage example from the package documentation encapsulated in a function.

```
# The function:

antonyms <- function(x){
  filter <- getTermFilter("ExactMatchFilter", x, TRUE)
  terms <- getIndexTerms("ADJECTIVE", 5, filter)
  synsets <- getSynsets(terms[[1]])
  related <- getRelatedSynsets(synsets[[1]], "!")
  sapply(related, getWord)
}

# Some words work while others return an error:

> antonyms("happy")
[1] "unhappy"
> antonyms("great")
Error in .jcall(l, "Ljava/util/Iterator;", "iterator") : 
  RcallMethod: invalid object parameter

# The Error is caused by the "related" step.
```

My goal here is to have a function that I can lapply vectors of words to in order to get their antonyms as output, much like the synonyms function provided by the package.

Thanks for any ideas :)

edit: 
I'm on:
OSX 10.8.5,
wordnet package (in R) wordnet_0.1-9 and wordnet 3.0_3 (system wide through macports),
rJava 0.9-4,
R version 3.0.1 (2013-05-16).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that *great* doesn't have direct antonyms. If you [look up *great* in WordNet Search](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?o2=&o0=1&o8=1&o1=1&o7=&o5=&o9=&o6=&o3=&o4=&s=great&i=30&h=0100100100101001010010100101000#c), you will see that all antonyms are *indirect via* some other word. You'd have to first go over the *similar to* relationships, and look up for antonyms there. On the contrary, [*happy* has a direct antonym](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?o2=&o0=1&o8=1&o1=1&o7=&o5=&o9=&o6=&o3=&o4=&s=happy&h=100010011001010100&j=2#c) (*opposed to*).

You might want to catch this specific error with a `tryCatch`:

```
antonyms <- function(x){
    filter <- getTermFilter("ExactMatchFilter", x, TRUE)
    terms <- getIndexTerms("ADJECTIVE", 5, filter)
    synsets <- getSynsets(terms[[1]])
    related <- tryCatch(
        getRelatedSynsets(synsets[[1]], "!"),
        error = function(condition) {
            message("No direct antonym found")
            if (condition$message == "RcallMethod: invalid object parameter")
                message("No direct antonym found")
            else
                stop(condition)
            return(NULL)
        }
    )
    if (is.null(related))
        return(NULL)
    return(sapply(related, getWord))
}
```

Comment: Thank you so very much! I'll post if I further refine the function but this is certainly a great start.